# How do I transform a word in a html textbox to a "tag" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to program a fancy searchbox.
Everytime when you type a word and then press the spacebar, the word should be transformed to a "tag". With "tag" I mean following:
[image: Tag from profile]

The tags you can see here are from my profile settings from stackoverflow. Here, a tag is created by pressing the "add"-Button. But I want the word to become a tag not by pressing a button, but everytime I press the spacebar.

Do you have any solutions for my problem?

I've searched for a long time in google, but i haven't found anything!

Thank you for your help!

:D

Comment: Something like this: [Tagit](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a problem so much as a feature. When you start coding and hit a roadblock, then you have a problem. Likely hundreds of ways to accomplish this. Give it a go and post your code when/if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/geop94u7/

Somewhat robust, can be packaged for re-use with some consideration (scoping, multi-instance, etc.).

First, the markup:

```
<div id="tags" class="cf"></div>
<input type="text" id="tagname" />
```

Then the JS, preventing duplicates, and allowing removal of already selected tags (which can be re-selected then).

```
$('#tagname').keypress(function(e) {
    var $t = $(e.target),
        tmap = $t.data('tmap') || {},
        n = e.keyCode || e.which,
        val;
    $t.data('tmap', tmap);

    if (n === 32) {
        val = $.trim($t.val());
        if (val !== '' && tmap[val] === undefined) {
            tmap[val] = 1;
            $('#tags').append($('<div>').addClass('tag').html(val));
            $t.val('');
        }
    }
});

$('#tags').on('click', '.tag', function(e) {
    var $t = $(e.target);
    txt = $.trim($t.text());
    $t.remove();
    delete $('#tagname').data('tmap')[txt];
});
```

Lastly, some run of the mill CSS with a delete indicator:

```
#tags {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

.tag {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.tag::after {
    content: '\2612';
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: -2px 0 0 10px;
}
```

You're better off using a robust plugin (there are quite a few) if rebuilding from scratch isn't a mandate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lexicalnoscope/4ouh7m97/. I kind of hate using jQuery for stuff like this, though, so it's in plain javascript. The script portion looks like this:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output'),
    input = document.querySelector('input');

    input.onkeyup = function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 32) { //check for spacebar
        var tag = document.createElement('span');
        tag.className = "tag";
        tag.textContent = input.value.trim();
        input.value = "";
        output.appendChild(tag)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is alright, but the problem is that it's not that smooth. If you look closely, everytime you press the spacebar, the space shows up and gets deleted.

Comment: Fair point. If that's a problem, the only change you need to make is to change `input.onkeyup` to `input.onkeydown`. Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lexicalnoscope/4ouh7m97/)